# Create block from another block

Tags: ruby, block, proc

Is it possible in ruby to alter parameters of a block to create another block?

I have a function like say `foo` and I have a block say `block` passed to me by the user. Now I want to pass `foo` a modified block say `modified_block`, which is similar to `block` but there's a slight different.

Assume `block` is defined as follows. It could be anything though since it's passed by user.

```
block = { |a,b| a <=> b }
```

I want my modified block to be like this

```
modified_block = { |a,b| func(a) <=> func(b) }
```

So, I basically want my `modified_block` to be same as `block` but `a` and `b` should be replaced by `func(a)` and `func(b)` respectively.

Is this possible to do?

I am looking for something like following that would do the trick

```
modified_block = block(func(a), func(b))
```

Comment: Why do you want to modify the block? Didn't the last example work for you?

Comment: No the last example didn't worked. It raised `undefined local variable or method 'a' for main:Object`

Comment: You cannot pass a block as it is not an object. You can pass a Proc object though.

Comment: @sawa I'm sorry. I realize after reading that it should be proc that has to be passed. Anyway, so is there a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (assuming you are working with `proc`s):

```
def func(a)
 0 - a
end

block = ->(a,b) { a <=> b}

modified_block = ->(a,b) { block.call(func(a), func(b)) }

block.call(1,2)
# => -1

modified_block.call(1,2)
# => 1
```